# Boot failure after upgrade to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade

I've recently tried to upgrade to 16.04.1 LTS.  I'm currently left with a system that will not boot.  The upgrade seemed to work fine since I did not get any error messages.  I was asked to reboot by the upgrade and I did.  Now, my system will not start.  I'm left with the following messages:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysint
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: clean, xxxxx files, xxxx blocks
saa7164_downloadfirmware() no first image
saa7164_downloadfirmware() Upload failed. (file not found?)
Failed to boot firmware, no features registered.
Welcome to Emergency mode!
```

I've seen lots of posts here with similar messages about "lvmetad", but, none that refer to the other types of messages I am receiving.  I've even tried the `Ctrl-Alt-F1` keypress to login as indicated by one of the posts with no luck.  I'm at a loss as to how to proceed as Ubuntu is not my native system.  Can this be repaired with a Live CD?  How should I proceed?

**EDIT: Aug. 20**

I've resolved some of my problems.  I found that the "*saa7164_downloadfirmware() no first image*" message was the result of a TV tuner card that I had installed several years ago, was no longer used, and never removed.  I removed it and still had problems.  I've tried several things at this point including using the Live CD to try a `dist-upgrade`.  I've also gone into recovery mode and tried some of the options there.  I found that I can successfully boot *only* if I use the **Upstart** option on the boot menu.  If I try to boot normally, I get the "recovering journal" message and a request to enter Emergency mode.  I'm still looking for some help on booting normally.

**EDIT: Aug. 22**

I've used the recovery tools and now I am presented with

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysint
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: clean, xxxxx files, xxxx blocks
```

Still can't boot cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem.  Unfortunately, I had to resort to the 'nuclear' option.  After several attempts at trying variously proposed solutions I found here and on other sites, I could not get the system to boot "normally".  The only way I could get it to boot was by specifying **Upstart** from the boot menu.  I decided to format my drive(s) and re-load from the Live CD.  This has resolved whatever problem was caused by upgrading my system.

Comment: were you able to fix the issue or just by doing clean new install was it fixe?

Comment: @Ken Sandoval as my answer states, the only way I could resolve the issue was to reinstall.